# Bifrost gives Internal server error 500

Tags: bifrost

I am getting an internal server error

```
if (requestData === undefined) {
      requestData = null;
    }

    // Send the request
    request.send(requestData); // The error is given at this line number 2046
  });
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Any errors in Bifrost log?